# CakePHP Mailgun Email with Attachment

Tags: php, curl, cakephp, mailgun

I have an app built with CakePHP 2.9 and am trying to send emails using mailgun. The emails get delivered with all of the needed content however attachments dont show up. Mailgun log looks good except for the attachment array being empty.

I was trying to send a dynamic file (pdf) however for testing purposes I've switched to a local png file and it still isn't working

I've been trying a few ways to get the attachment to be added but havent been able to here is the code

Email code

```
$Email = new CakeEmail('mailgun');
$Email->template('pdf');
$Email->emailFormat('html');
$Email->to($email);
$Email->subject($configdata['Config']['accountstatementsubject']);
$Path = WWW_ROOT."pdf/";
$fileName = 'Account_'.$usersGenrate['User']['fname'].'.pdf';

$Email->attachments(WWW_ROOT.'img/bg.png');
$Email->viewVars(array('emailcontent' => $configdata['Config']['accountstatementcontent'],
                        'user' => $usersGenrate['User']));
$Email->send();
```

Here is the CurlTransport.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Mailgun curl class
 *
 * Enables sending of email over mailgun via curl
 *
 * Licensed under The MIT License
 * 
 * @author Brad Koch <bradkoch2007@gmail.com>
 * @license MIT License (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php)
 */
class CurlTransport extends AbstractTransport {
/**
 * Configurations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    protected $_config = array();
/**
 * Send mail
 *
 * @params CakeEmail $email
 * @return array
 */
    public function send(CakeEmail $email) {
        $post = array();
        $post_preprocess = array_merge(
            $email->getHeaders(array('from', 'sender', 'replyTo', 'readReceipt', 'returnPath', 'to', 'cc', 'bcc', 'subject')),
            array(
                'text' => $email->message(CakeEmail::MESSAGE_TEXT),
                'html' => $email->message(CakeEmail::MESSAGE_HTML)
            )
        );
        foreach ($post_preprocess as $k => $v) {
            if (! empty($v)) {
                $post[strtolower($k)] = $v;
            }
        }

        if ($attachments = $email->attachments()) {
            $i = 1;
            foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
                $post['attachment[' . $i . ']'] = "@" . $attachment["file"];
                $i++;
            }
        }
        $ch = curl_init('https://api.mailgun.net/v2/' . $this->_config['mailgun_domain'] . '/messages');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'api:' . $this->_config['api_key']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        if ($response === false) {
            throw new SocketException("Curl had an error.  Message: " . curl_error($ch), 500);
        }
        $http_status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        if ($http_status != 200) {
            throw new SocketException("Mailgun request failed.  Status: $http_status, Response: $response", 500);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        return array(
            'headers' => $this->_headersToString($email->getHeaders(), PHP_EOL),
            'message' => implode(PHP_EOL, $email->message())
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked whether your transport creates the expected post data? Also what's your exact PHP and CakePHP version?

Comment: Aplogies, forgot to specify its CakePHP 2.9 - the mailgun log says it's receiving all the post data except for the attachment :/

Comment: I understand, but what I mean is checking the data in your transport before it's actually being sent. Also what's your PHP version?

Comment: Latest PHP version, actually i didn't think about double checking the data you were right, double checking made me realize it wasn't being done correctly. I'm still new to all of this  so i dont always think of everything 

Heres the link i used to see what was being produced
https://ptsv2.com/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated code to work with attachments

Basically changed the line
From

```
$post['attachment[' . $i . ']'] = "@" . $attachment["file"];
```

To

```
$post['attachment[' . $i . ']'] = curl_file_create($attachment["file"]);
```

Full code

```
<?php
/**
 * Mailgun curl class
 *
 * Enables sending of email over mailgun via curl
 *
 * Licensed under The MIT License
 * 
 * @author Brad Koch <bradkoch2007@gmail.com>
 * @license MIT License (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php)
 */
class CurlTransport extends AbstractTransport {
/**
 * Configurations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    protected $_config = array();
/**
 * Send mail
 *
 * @params CakeEmail $email
 * @return array
 */
    public function send(CakeEmail $email) {
        $post = array();
        $post_preprocess = array_merge(
            $email->getHeaders(array('from', 'sender', 'replyTo', 'readReceipt', 'returnPath', 'to', 'cc', 'bcc', 'subject')),
            array(
                'text' => $email->message(CakeEmail::MESSAGE_TEXT),
                'html' => $email->message(CakeEmail::MESSAGE_HTML)
            )
        );
        foreach ($post_preprocess as $k => $v) {
            if (! empty($v)) {
                $post[strtolower($k)] = $v;
            }
        }
        if ($attachments = $email->attachments()) {
            $i = 1;
            foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
                $post['attachment[' . $i . ']'] = curl_file_create($attachment["file"]);
                $i++;
            }
        }

        /*$ch = curl_init('https://ptsv2.com/t/82b3y-1563814313/post');*/
        $ch = curl_init('https://api.mailgun.net/v2/' . $this->_config['mailgun_domain'] . '/messages');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'api:' . $this->_config['api_key']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        if ($response === false) {
            throw new SocketException("Curl had an error.  Message: " . curl_error($ch), 500);
        }
        $http_status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        if ($http_status != 200) {
            throw new SocketException("Mailgun request failed.  Status: $http_status, Response: $response", 500);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        return array(
            'headers' => $this->_headersToString($email->getHeaders(), PHP_EOL),
            'message' => implode(PHP_EOL, $email->message())
        );
    }
}
```